# How to add a permission to an AD App with Pulumi

Tags: azure, pulumi

I try to add the "Sign in and read user profile" permission to my app, but I can't find how to do it.

Here is the code I have now

```js
const myApp= new azure.ad.Application("myApp", {
    name: "myApp",
    availableToOtherTenants: false,
    homepage: "https://homepage",
    identifierUris: ["https://uri"],
    oauth2AllowImplicitFlow: true,
    replyUrls: ["https://replyurl"]
});

const myAppPrincipal= new azure.ad.ServicePrincipal("myAppPrincipal", {
    applicationId: myApp.applicationId,
});
```

How to do the permission with Pulumi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not possible, pulumi depends on terraform, and terraform has no graph resources, only ARM stuff.

new azure ad provider (right now identical to old one): https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azuread/index.html

Comment: Ok, so the only way to solve that at the moment is to add an ARM template in my index.ts to solve this part?

Comment: arm template cannot add azure ad roles as well

Comment: you can use nodejs sdk to assign those

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/activedirectory?view=azure-node-latest